# WCF REST Service aspCompatibilityMode not working in IIS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, rest

Trying to deploy a wcf rest service inside of an asp.net web application. Works wonderfully when deploying to test server in visual studio, however when i deploy to iis 6 I get nothing. It is as if my service is not there at all.

here is my web config under system.service model:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

and im registering a route in the global.cs

```
routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service", new WebServiceHostFactory3(), typeof(WcfJQueryService)));
```

my web service class is decorated with:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

I am using windows authentication if that matters in this case...

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work via the instructions in this article...

http://hackprogrammer.blogspot.com/2009/01/installing-wcf-on-iis6.html

running aspnet_regiis -i for .net4.0 got me up and running